# Spring access application context staticly

Tags: spring

I have a class like this:

```
public class Spring implements ApplicationContextAware{

    private static ApplicationContext CONTEXT;

    public static <T> T getBean(Class<T> clz){
        return CONTEXT.getBean(clz);
    }

    public static Object getBean(String s){
        return CONTEXT.getBean(s);
    }

    public static <T> T getBean(String s, Class<T> clz){
        return CONTEXT.getBean(s, clz);
    }

    public static Object getBean(String s, Object... objs){
        return CONTEXT.getBean(s, objs);
    }

    @Override
    // TODO how to protect this method ?
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext ac) throws BeansException {    
        Spring.CONTEXT = ac;
    }

    public static <T> T eal(Object o, String expression, Class<T> clz){
        ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
        Expression exp = parser.parseExpression(expression);
        return exp.getValue(o, clz);
    }

}
```

defined like  this:

```
<bean id="springApplicationContext" class="org.codingfarm.cwe.Spring"/>
```

but the `setApplicationContext` method is public, how can I protected this method from client code ?

by the way, is this a bad practice in real world application?

Any better way to do what I want?

### **Edit:**

I think I can do a null check  like this :

```
public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext ac) throws BeansException {
        if(CONTEXT == null)
            CONTEXT = ac;
    }
```

then do I need to clear this static CONTEXT field when servlet container reload my application ?

Answer (score 1):

> by the way, is this a bad practice in real world application?

Yes this is pretty bad practice. It's basically the opposite of dependency injection. By using static methods to access beans in your `ApplicationContext` you've destroyed the ability to test any of your code or benefit from the dependency injection pattern.

You should be using `@Inject` to obtain instances of your classes which are already wired with their dependencies via their constructor.